# Overwriting records when number of items in collection goes more than three

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to write list of items to Firebase collection but when there are already three items I need it to overwrite existing value. So that the number of items in the collection stays less than equal to three.

Currently I am checking the count and deleting before setting new value

```
  const count = await connection()
    .collection(`someCollection`)
    .count();

  if(count === 3) {
   // delete last record
   }

  const someCollection = await connection()
    .collection(`someCollection`)
    .doc();

  someCollection.set({
    history
  });
```

Could I do this in a single query.

Comment: Since you need at most three items, did you consider storing them all in a single document?

Comment: so if I were using a single document how would I still do the above in a single query. Since each of the records are generated separately they are meant to serve as history for simple user event

Comment: If you store all three records in a single document, you'd just load that document, check the number of records in there, and update accordingly. Depending on which one you want to remove (oldest or newest), using an array might be easiest (since you can use `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, `prepend`, and `append` operations).

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen It was dumb of me not to think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need at most three items, I'd consider storing them all in a single document.

That way you'd just load that document, check the number of records in there, and update accordingly.

Depending on which one you want to remove (oldest or newest), using an array might be easiest (since you can use `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, `prepend`, and `append` operations).